# How to hide Android status bar in native game written with gomobile

Tags: android, go, mobile, opengl-es, gomobile

How to hide Android status bar in native game written with gomobile?

I am experimenting with a simple native Android game written in pure Go using the gomobile tool. It should be able to use the full screen for rendering frames. However I could not find an API to hide the status bar from the native app.

Has anyone tackled this issue? If so, please share the directions.

Comment: find the solution in android side, and call from native with gomobile RPC

Comment: @JiangYD RPC would call a method of a server. What server would one call from the native Android game?

Comment: not strict, the inter-operation between go and java is a kind of RPC.

Comment: @JiangYD Can you point how a pure Go Android app would call a method from an Android lib written in Java?

Comment: The gomobile document shows it.

Comment: @JiangYD No, it doesn't. gomobile doc only shows how to call a Go lib from a Java app. However it does not show how to call a Java lib from a native Go app.

Comment: http://godoc.org/golang.org/x/mobile/cmd/gobind

Comment: "Gobind generates language bindings that make it possible to call Go functions from Java and Objective-C."

Comment: http://godoc.org/golang.org/x/mobile/cmd/gobind#hdr-Passing_target_language_objects_to_Go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how to disable the Android status bar in a native application written with gomobile:

Add this exact theme to AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<activity android:name="org.golang.app.GoNativeActivity"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
</activity>
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a Empty Activity .
Go and find

`android:theme=""` on Activity XML Files

Set it to `@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar`

> **Pro Tip :**
>
> dont know other people but I always delete
>
> ```
> Menu/Menu_Activity.Xml
> ```
>
> That Contains Menu XML files !
>
> Also Remove `Menu.OnClick` Codes Located on The `Class` of Your
>   Activity

**Update** :

Emm ... did you change :

```
public class Setup extends ActionBarActivity {
```

to

```
public class Setup extends Activity {
```

???

Comment: Does this make sense for a gomobile native app? I think gomobile works only with GoNativeActivity activity. Look at this example: https://github.com/golang/mobile/blob/master/example/network/AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: As far as I know, the gomobile app does use Java files. Where in the gomobile project is one supposed to edit the Java class?

Answer (score 0):

On the manifest add: theme: Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar

For each activity page in which you dont want to show the status bar

Comment: gomobile tool reports this error --> gomobile: apk: Create(classes.dex): spec by name not found: "@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"

Comment: <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        </activity>

Comment: I think gomobile requires GoNativeActivity: <activity android:name="org.golang.app.GoNativeActivity"
  android:label="network"
  android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
  android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"> However it reports: gomobile: apk: Create(classes.dex): spec by name not found: "@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"

Comment: Ohh ok ok, that makes sense. I am not quite familiar with gomobile